# Ubuntu on WDMyCloud NAS WDBCTL0020HWT-EESN

Tags: system-installation, nas, nextcloud

I have a WD MyCloud 2TB NAS [WDBCTL0020HWT-EESN](https://www.wdc.com/en-ie/products/personal-cloud-storage/my-cloud.html#!) running BusyBox Linux v1.20.2 and as I am getting a lot of sync errors I would like to flush the BusyBox and replace it with Ubuntu and install NextCloud on it.

**Edit 1**

Busybox is rather limited with the choice of commands to view hardware info so here is my humble try to get some hardware info to ask if Ubuntu is compliant with this.

**The built-in processor:**

```
root@XXXXX root # cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 1594.16
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x4
CPU part        : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 1

processor       : 1
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 1594.16
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x4
CPU part        : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 1

Hardware        : Marvell Armada 375 (Device Tree)
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```

**Memory**

```
root@XXXXX root # cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:         514528 kB
MemFree:          106240 kB
Buffers:           39040 kB
Cached:           175168 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           117600 kB
Inactive:         160960 kB
Active(anon):      57376 kB
Inactive(anon):    24768 kB
Active(file):      60224 kB
Inactive(file):   136192 kB
Unevictable:        6464 kB
Mlocked:            6464 kB
HighTotal:             0 kB
HighFree:              0 kB
LowTotal:         514528 kB
LowFree:          106240 kB
SwapTotal:       2097056 kB
SwapFree:        2097056 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         70720 kB
Mapped:            52864 kB
Shmem:             15616 kB
Slab:              37280 kB
SReclaimable:      13728 kB
SUnreclaim:        23552 kB
KernelStack:        1672 kB
PageTables:        13312 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     2354304 kB
Committed_AS:     392480 kB
VmallocTotal:     515072 kB
VmallocUsed:        7712 kB
VmallocChunk:     490496 kB
```

Disk Partitions

```
root@XXXXX root # df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
%root%                   55529     33808     18854  64% /
/dev/ram0                55529     33808     18854  64% /
mdev                    257248        32    257216   0% /dev
/dev/sda3               999576    211756    761116  22% /boot
/dev/sda7               999576      1684    971188   0% /usr/local/config
/dev/loop0              102144    102144         0 100% /usr/local/modules
tmpfs                     1024         0      1024   0% /mnt
tmpfs                    40960      8320     32640  20% /var/log
tmpfs                   102400      1728    100672   2% /tmp
/dev/sda4               951192      2384    932424   0% /mnt/HD_a4
/dev/sda2            1914463512   4762048 1890233996   0% /mnt/HD/HD_a2
```

Linux/Kernel Info

```
root@XXXXX root # cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.39 (kman@kmachine) (gcc version 4.6.4 (Linaro GCC branch-4.6.4. Marvell GCC Dev 201310-2126.3d181f66 64K MAXPAGESIZE ALIGN) ) #1 SMP Sun Aug 2 12:24:50 CST 2015 2014T20p4 Build-git3e9fe59
```

Can Ubuntu 16.04 lts server or Ubuntu Core run on this architecture?

**Edit 2**

If Ubuntu supports the ARMADA 375, how can this be installed on this headless NAS?

Comment: https://community.wd.com/t/clean-os-debian-openmediavault-and-other-firmwares/93714

Comment: Hi, I went through your post. Is there a way I can do without using the WD Recovery as I really don't like it at all and have 16.04 Lts server instead.

Comment: That's not actually my post. It's just something I found. But, this question is not really suited for this site. I think you'd be better off asking on the WD forums.

Comment: Please vide Edit 2. I still need to find out if Ubuntu is compliant with the Armada 375 before I attempt the install, not to brick the device.

Comment: @Fab: According to AndroidDev's link one can run Debian on those devices so Ubuntu should work too and, most importantly, will not brick the device as you can just put the old operating system back onto the hard drive. You could even create a clone of the current state as a backup.

Comment: @David Foerster Thanks for that. The problem that remains is how to do the install on this headless NAS

Comment: That wasn't your question though. You only asked if the hardware supports Ubuntu. You can [open a new question](/questions/ask) if you want.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I had done such in Edit 2